# Recover Application data after Android force shuts down process in background

Tags: android

I've tested my app on a low memory device. After I launch another application my app's process gets killed. After I return to my app the backstack gets recreated.

Problem is that my app holds some data(retrieved from a remote server) in `Application` object, which, obviously,in case of process termination gets lost. So the app crushes due to fragment accessing null references.

The data stored in Application is fairly complex - so I don't think saving it as a `Bundle` is a good idea. Another approach with a database, just for this scenario, seems to be a bit of a overkill. I could recover data (in a separate `BootstrapFragment`) after the app recreates but I'm not sure how to handle back presses until data is loaded because underlying fragments would crush due to data not being yet fetched.

Could you suggest anything? Thanks.

Comment: "in Application object" Where is that?

Comment: If you're getting it from the server, it's probably already in some format like JSON, no? Why not save the JSON data to the SharedPreferences when the App is destroyed and then reload via that if it exists?